# Console.log on a random number

Tags: function, console, console.log

How do I create a separate function where if my randNum = 7 it will console.log "hello". Using only javascript.

Thanks.

```
function randomNumber() {
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;
        console.log(randNum);

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function randomNumber() {

    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;

    return randNum;

}

function logRandomNumber() {

    var randNum = randomNumber();

    if(randNum == 7) { 

        console.log('hello');

    }

}

logRandomNumber();
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would put the console.log  in a separate function though.

Comment: like this?

function randomNumber() {

 var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;

 return randNum;

}

function logRandomNumber() {

 var randNum = randomNumber();

 if(randNum == 7) { 

  console.log('hello');

 }

}

logRandomNumber();

Comment: function randomNumber() {

  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;

  return randNum;

 }

 function logRandomNumber() {

  var randNum = randomNumber();

  if(randNum == 7) { 

   console.log('hello');

  }

 }

 logRandomNumber();

Comment: Happy to help, can you mark it as the correct answer please?

Answer (score 1):

```
function randomNumber() 
{
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;
        (randNum==7)?console.log("hello"):console.log(randNum); 

}
```

// if you need another function

```
function randomNumber1() 
{
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;
        if(randNum===7)
          SeparateFunc();


}

function SeparateFunc(){
console.log("hello");

}
```

> JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y918ndu0/

Answer (score 0):

```
  function randomNumber() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;
    if(randNum == 7){
      hello();
    }

  }

 function hello(){
   console.log('hello');
 }
```

wrap the console log in a if statement which checks the value of the random number that was generated.

The new function will have the console log and will be called when the if statement is correct

```
function randomNumber() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;
      hello(randNum);
  }

 function hello(randNum){
   if(randNum == 7)
    console.log('hello');
   }
}
```

so you pass the randNum variable to the function where it will checked

Comment: He meant _Hello_, not _7_ (:-).

Comment: woops, just then console log "hello" instead

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would put the console.log in a separate function though.

Comment: create a new function which will contain the console.log('hello') and call it within the if statement

Comment: ` function randomNumber() {
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (25)) + 1;
    if(randNum == 7){
      console.log(randNum);
    }

  }`

Comment: So there is no way of having the if statement in the separate function.